# "svn up" misses files!

Tags: svn

When trying to do an `svn up` I get the normal `At revision XX` even though some files are missing, the missing files do show when doing an `svn list` example:

```
$ svn list
> ConditionTest.java
> persistence
$ ls
> persistence
$ svn list
> ConditionTest.java
> persistence/
$ svn up
> Is at revision 55
$ ls
> persistence
```

The file ConditionTest.java is not added unless manually running `svn up ConditionTest.java`

What is up? Can't I trust svn anymore? Running svn, version 1.6.6 (r40053)

Answer (score 1):

Is there a property asking to ignore this file ? `svn propget svn:ignore .` should display that.
I don't use `svn list`, but `svn status`, with the state of the files.

Comment: There are no properties set at all and svn status -u does not show the files missing

Comment: If you use -u it check with the update. Check in local (without -u) to see if a special condition is given.

Comment: A normal svn status does not show any edits